# how C++ ensures the concept of base class and derived class

Tags: c++

I would like to know how c++ ensures the concept layout in memory of these classes to support inheritance.

for example:

```
class Base1
{

    public:
        void function1(){cout<<"Base1"};

};

class Base2
{

    public:
        void function2(){cout<<"Base2"};

};

class MDerived: Base1,Base2
{

    public:
        void function1(){cout<<"MDerived"};

};

void function(Base1 *b1)
{

    b1->function1();
}
```

So when I pass function an object of derived type the function should offset into the base1 class function and call it. How does C++ ensure such a layout.

Comment: Your `MDerived::function1` method was printing "Base1", which is not what I think you intended.  I've edited your post.

Comment: Can some please lay the memory layout the compiler should generate. and how the derived object is casted to base class. Because there are two base classes in derived memory how does compiler know about which offset to pick.

Comment: The standard doesn't define a memory layout, that's left up to implementers. Strictly speaking every answer in this question is talking about a platform specific way that some compilers use to implement virtual functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `MDerived*` needs to be converted to a `Base1*`, the compiler adjusts the pointer to point to the correct memory address, where the members of this base class are located. This means that a `MDerived*` that is cast to a `Base1*` might point to a different memory address than the original `MDerived*` (depending on the memory layout of the derived class).

The compiler can do this because it knows the memory layout of all the classes, and when a cast occurs it can add code that adjusts the address of the pointer.

For example this might print different addresses:

```
int main() {
   MDerived *d = new MDerived;
   std::cout << "derived: " << d << std::endl;
   std::cout << "base1: " << (base1*)d << std::endl;
   std::cout << "base2: " << (base2*)d << std::endl;
}
```

In your example such adjustments might not be necessary since the classes don't contain any member variables that would use any memory in the sub-objects representing the base classes. If you have a pointer pointing to "nothing" (no member variables), it doesn't really matter if that nothing is called `Base1` or `Base2` or `MDerived`.

The non-virtual methods of the classes are not stored with each object, they are stored only once. The compiler then statically, at compile time, uses those global addresses when a member function is called, according to the type of the variable used.

Answer (score 0):

The layout of a class in memory includes its members and *base class subobjects* (§10/2). Members are also subobjects. A pointer to a base subobject is a pointer to an object (but not a most-derived object).

When you convert an `MDerived *` to a `Base2 *`, the compiler looks up the offset of the `Base2` object inside the `MDerived` object and uses it to generate `this` for the inherited method.

Comment: how does the compiler know about the offset. Does it store somewhere ?

Comment: It's part of the definition of the structure. It's remembered by the compiler, but not directly stored in the compiled program. You could say it's "stored" in the ADD instruction that generates the base pointer from the derived pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're asking why, when you call `b1->function()`, does `Base1::function1()` fire?

If so, then the reason is because `b1` is a `Base1` pointer, not a `MDerived` pointer.  The object it points to may in fact "be" an `MDerived` object, but `function(Base1*)` has no way of knowing this, so it calls the only thing it does know -- `Base1::function1()`.

Now, if you had marked the base class function as `virtual`, things change:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Base1 
{
public: virtual void function1() { cout<<"Base1"; }
};

class Base2 
{
public: void function2(){cout<<"Base2";}
};

class MDerived: public Base1, public Base2 
{
public: void function1(){cout<<"MDerived";}
};

void function(Base1 *b1) 
{
    b1->function1();
}

int main()
{
    MDerived d;
    function(&d);
}
```

The output of the program is:

"MDerived"

`void function(Base1 *b1)` still doesn't know that the object being pointed to is actually an `MDerived`, but now it doesn't have to.  WHen you call `virtual` functions through a base class pointer, you get [polymorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism) behavior.  Which in this case means `MDerived::function1()` is called because that is the most-derived type available.

Answer (score 0):

Few things in your code

1. The multiple inheritance should be public, else the compiler will complain that there is no access to the base classes
2. No `;` at the end of the cout statements
3. Did not include the `<iostream>` (ok may be I am being too pedantic)

To answer your question - the compiler knows that it is the base class because the type of the argument that the function is taking is Base1. The compiler converts the type of the passed data (assuming you passed a derived object, does object slicing) and then calls the function1() on it (which is a simple offset from the base pointer calculation).